# How to use useEffect correctly to apply modifications to the array state using Firestore?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm using React firebase to make a Slack like chat app. I am listening to the change of the state inside the useEffect on rendering. (dependency is []).

The problem I have here is, how to fire the changes when onSnapshot listener splits out the changed state. If change.type is "modified", I use modifyCandidate (which is an interim state) to save what's been updated, and hook this state in the second useEffect.

The problem of second effect is, without dependency of chats, which is the array of chat, there is no chat in chats (which is obviously true in the initial rendering). To get chats, I add another dependency to second effect. Now, other problem I get is whenever I face changes or addition to the database, the second effect is fired even if modification didn't take place.

How can I effectively execute second effect when only modification occurs as well as being able to track the changes of chats(from the beginning) or

am I doing something awkward in the listening phase?

Please share your thoughts! (:

```
  useEffect(() => {
      const chatRef = db.collection('chat').doc('room_' + channelId).collection('messages')
      chatRef.orderBy("created").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      snapshot.docChanges().forEach((change) => {
        if (change.type === "added") {
            console.log("New message: ", change.doc.data());
        }
        if (change.type === "modified") {
          console.log("Modified message: ", change.doc.data());
          setModifyCandidate(change.doc.data());  
        }
        if (change.type === "removed") {
          console.log("remove message: ", change.doc.data());
        }
      });
    });
  }, [])

  useEffect(() => {
    if(!modifyCandidate){
      return
    }
    const copied = [...chats];
    const index = copied.findIndex(chat => chat.id === modifyCandidate.id)
    copied[index] = modifyCandidate
    setChats(copied)
  }, [modifyCandidate, chats])
```

initially, I also use this useEffect to load chats.

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const chatRef = db.collection('chat').doc('room_' + channelId).collection('messages')
    chatRef.orderBy("created").get().then((snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data(),
      }));
      setChats(data);
    })
  }, []) 



return <>

{
chats.map((chat) => {
      return <div key={chat.id}>
        <ChatCard chat={chat} users={users} uid={uid} index={chat.id} onEmojiClick={onEmojiClick}/>
      </div>
    })
}
</>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use useMemo instead of 2nd useEffect.

```
  const chat = useMemo(() => {
    if(!modifyCandidate){
      return null
    }
    const copied = [...chats];
    const index = copied.findIndex(chat => chat.id === modifyCandidate.id)
    copied[index] = modifyCandidate

    return copied
  }, [modifyCandidate])
```

Comment: Hi, in this case, where should chat be used? If we use chat inside chats, then every chat will try to copy entire chats, which a bit redundant thing here. Could you elaborate this a bit?

Comment: in order for me to elaborate i have to first see your return block ( and other codes), at this moment I do not know what does chat and chats represent, and don't really know what your code does. The code i provided is based on your useEffect block statement converted to useMemo so you don't need to use chat and setChat, and doesn't cause unnecessary rerenders.

Comment: I add the what's in the return! chats state is an array that has chat. chat is simple json!

Comment: I assumed your question is answered?